# Apache Velocity access String array created in Java code?

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to access a String array which i have created in my Java class.
The string array is stored in a Map with the name 'notSelected' using the same key.

I also have a single String object called 'testString' stored in the same Map which i can easily access and display using:

`$testString`

However how do i go about accessing the String array object (notSelected) from the Map inside the velocity template object?

I have tried:

`$notSelected.get(0)`
`$notSelected[0]`
`$notSelected.[0]`
`${notSelected}.get(0)`

The last three seem to return the reference value of the memory location of the String array object but i still can't access the values inside the array.

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks

Here is the java code:

```
public Map<String, Object> getVelocityParameters
        (final Issue issue, final CustomField field, final FieldLayoutItem fieldLayoutItem) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = super.getVelocityParameters(issue, field, fieldLayoutItem);
    String[] notSelected = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    map.put("notSelected", notSelected);

    String[] selected = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    map.put("selected", selected);

    //this code works and i can access $testString in the velocity template
    String testString = "Test Worked";
    map.put("testString", testString);

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the pseudocode that puts them into the velocity context? I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: And that map is put into the context, or... how is it exposed to the template?

Comment: yea that map is in the context. so i can print and output the 'testString' variable...but i also want to access the string arrays...so for example how would i access notSelected[0], which would work in Java, in the template? Thanks Dave

Comment: How is the map being put into the context? Without knowing how you're setting up and executing this it's difficult to help efficiently. When I put an array into the velocity context I have no issues using normal square-bracket notation.

Comment: Someone else coded that but does that really matter considering i can access the String and int and double etc just not the arrays?

Comment: Yes, it does, because without knowing what else is happening, it's difficult to understand why normal Velocity context access would suddenly not work.

Comment: ok...something like this: context.put ("map", map )?

Comment: How are you able to access the map contents directly without referring to the context entry key?

Comment: I am not sure of the version of velocity. I have only just set up the IDE so im assuming the latest i.e. 1.7

Comment: I don't know how im able to access the String without using the 'map' variable?

Comment: What is `getVelocityParameters` from? Are you trying to customize JIRA?

Comment: Did you try a list instead of an array? (Checking Velocity version now--it's 1.4.)

Comment: Ok so JIRA uses velocity version 1.4?? So ill try a list then?

Comment: And make sure you accept answers, particularly after above-and-beyond efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JIRA uses an older version of Velocity that does not support array index notation for accessing arrays. Instead, use a `List` and `.get(n)` notation:

```
List foo = new ArrayList() {{ add("hi"); add("there"); }};

$foo.get(0)
$foo.get(1)
```

And remember, little tidbits of info like the environment you're operating in can make a huge difference (and when someone asks a question, there may be a reason for asking it ;)

Comment: Cool. (I wonder why they use an old version? If I remember, I'll ask.)