# Velocity lexical error when commenting out a line at file end

Tags: java, jira, velocity

I have the following Velocity template in JIRA (note, extra lines kept in):

```
NOTE: Please REPLY-TO this email when replying to this issue.

##parse("templates/email/includes/issueplugins.vm")
#if($comment.getId())[ ${baseurl}/browse/${issue.getKey()} ] #end ##?page=${tabpanel-comment}&focusedCommentId=${comment.getId()}#action_${comment.getId()} ] #end


#if($remoteUser.fullName)
$i18n.getText("template.issue.commented.on", $remoteUser.fullName, $issue.getKey())
#dashes($!remoteUser.fullName)--------------#dashes($issue.getKey())-
#end
#if($changelog)

#changes([])
#end
#comment()
#visibility()

#parse("templates/email/text/includes/issuesummary.vm")

#parse("templates/email/text/includes/footer.vm")
```

There is no line following that last line. When do I this on the very last line:

```
##parse("templates/email/text/includes/footer.vm")
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred whilst rendering this message.  Please contact the administrators, and inform them of this bug.

Details:
-------
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error:
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: 
        Lexical error at line 20, column 51.  Encountered: &lt;EOF&gt; after : &quot;&quot;
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.evaluate(VelocityEngine.java:272)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.evaluate(VelocityEngine.java:202)
...
```

I found the following issue from 2004:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-272

Which seems to suggest this was a bug fixed in 1.5. Checking in my JIRA System Info, I see that JIRA 4.2.1 appears to suggest version 1.6 is in use:

> Atlassian Template Renderer Velocity 1.6 Plugin - 1.1.1

When I move the line starting `#if($comment.getId())` to the end, the error goes away. Am I doing something wrong here at the end of the template, or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

Hmm. When I did this:

```
#if($comment.getId())[ ${baseurl}/browse/${issue.getKey()} ] #end ##?page=${tabpanel-comment}&focusedCommentId=${comment.getId()}#action_${comment.getId()} ] #end
```

As the last line, with no empty line following it, I got the same error. However, if I add a line after that line (just hit `ENTER` once), it works.

Do Velocity template's require an ending space? I'm confused.

Comment: You'd need to see which Velocity is actually being used to render the template; default JIRA ships with Velocity 1.4.

Comment: Not sure; I don't know anything about the plugin, so I don't know what it's supposed to do, or how it interacts with the rest of JIRA.

Comment: How do you know that it ships with 1.4? I've got version 4.2.1, and current is 4.4 (5 beta just released); surely, they've updated Velocity since then. Surely...

Comment: Downvote on question is retribution related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131139/convert-this-formula-to-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~/tech/atlassian/atlassian-jira-4.4.1-standalone $ find . -name "*velocity*.jar"
./atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib/velocity-1.4-atlassian-9.jar
./atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib/velocity-tools-1.3.jar
./atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib/atlassian-velocity-0.8.jar
```

And no, they haven't; see [this discussion from a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656321/apache-velocity-access-string-array-created-in-java-code)..

Comment: Yes, of course. I like a lot of the Atlassian products, but sometimes... Thank you! `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish You could also ask them, if it's an Atlassian plugin--I did a quick search for it but didn't run across it; if I have some time later I'll poke around a bit. (I don't understand the ancient Velocity either--some of the best products out there, but yeah :/

Comment: I thought it was a Velocity issue when I created the question; looking at the JIRA plugin, it seemed to suggest they were on a more recent version (1.6). I looked around as well, but didn't think to search like you did. That was how I ended up with the edit. I was actually about to delete the question in the next day or so, so I'm glad you noticed it. Atlassian makes a lot of "screwy" decisions (at least to us plebes) in their development priorities.

Comment: And asking the official support would have been a 24-48 hour turnaround (as a low-priority question). I always seem to get a support clerk based on the Gold Coast. I probably would have just let it ride.